# DataprocCreateClusterOperator fails due to TypeError

Tags: protocol-buffers, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

EDIT 1: The problem is related to the field `"initialization_actions"`. Originally I'd put a String there, now I gave it the object it's asking for:

```
from google.cloud.dataproc_v1beta2 import NodeInitializationAction

CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
    ...
    "initialization_actions": NodeInitializationAction({
        "executable_file": <string>})]
}
```

Unfortunately it's still complaining:

```
ERROR - Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.NodeInitializationAction got NodeInitializationAction.
```

---

I am trying to deploy a Dataproc cluster with `airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc.DataprocCreateClusterOperator`, but I get a cryptic `TypeError`.

Here is the task definition:

```
CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
    "config_bucket": <my_bucket>,
    "temp_bucket": <my_bucket>,
    "master_config": {
        "num_instances": 1,
        "machine_type_uri": "c2-standard-8",
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
    },
    "initialization_actions": [<string>],
}

create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
    task_id="create_cluster",
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
    region=REGION,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    metadata=[("ENV", ENV)],
    dag=dag)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 985, in _run_raw_tas
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 603, in execut
    cluster = self._create_cluster(hook
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py", line 540, in _create_cluste
    metadata=self.metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/common/hooks/base_google.py", line 425, in inner_wrappe
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/dataproc.py", line 304, in create_cluste
    metadata=metadata
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/dataproc_v1beta2/services/cluster_controller/client.py", line 412, in create_cluste
    request = clusters.CreateClusterRequest(request
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/message.py", line 506, in __init_
    pb_value = marshal.to_proto(pb_type, value
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/marshal/marshal.py", line 208, in to_prot
    pb_value = rule.to_proto(value
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/proto/marshal/rules/message.py", line 32, in to_prot
    return self._descriptor(**value
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected google.cloud.dataproc.v1beta2.NodeInitializationAction got str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field `initialization_actions" is not a list of strings, but a list of dicts:

```
"initialization_actions": [{"executable_file": <string>}]
```